# Form worked on 1 and 1 host but not working on correct host

Tags: php, html, forms, http, http-status-code-405

I have a form which I created in an asp page and this submits to a php page. This was working when I tested it in my host which is not where I want the files. I added it to the 1and1 host as this is what I use more frequently just to test it.

I needed it for my uncles site that is hosted on fasthost and the problem is I receive this error when I press send:

```
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
```

I don't understand this worked on 1and1 why would this not work on fasthost when I upload the files there?

I would highly appreciate any answers.

Thanks

Edit: 
I have searched and searched and come across help files.
This problem seems to be something to do with the actual host and adding -f into the php file. I have still not got this working but would appreciate any help on this. The page I saw this on is http://www.fasthosts.co.uk/knowledge-base/?article_id=70

I have edited the php file and this is not working the php code is:

```
 <?php


$name= $_POST['frmName'];
$email_from = $_POST['frmEmail'];
$field_phone = $_POST['frmPhone'];
$field_address = $_POST['frmAddress'];
$field_referral = $_POST['frmReferral'];
$field_frmCallback = $_POST['frmCallback'];
$field_frmEnquiry = $_POST['frmEnquiry'];

$email_to = 'info@moroccanpropertiesltd.com';


$body_message = 'From: '.$name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email_from."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Address: '.$field_address."\n";
$body_message .= 'Referral: '.$field_referral."\n";
$body_message .= 'Callback: '.$field_frmCallback."\n";
$body_message .= 'Enquiry: '.$field_frmEnquiry;

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$frmEmail."\r\n";
$subject = "Moroccan Properties Customer";


 $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";


$message = "This is a MIME encoded message."; 

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
 $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
 $message .= "This is the text/plain version.";

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
 $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
 $message .= "This is the <b>text/html</b> version.";

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

 ini_set("sendmail_from", "info@moroccanpropertiesltd.com");

$mail_status = mail($email_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers, "-finfo@moroccanpropertiesltd.com");

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'http://www.moroccanpropertiesltd.com/contact.asp';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@moroccanpropertiesltd.com');
        window.location = 'url';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I would be highly grateful if someone could point out what I have done wrong.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.supportsages.com/blog/2010/02/http-405-the-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your hosting isn't setup to host .php pages?  Have you tried using the .asp version?  Usually you don't mix the two scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable scripting with Fasthosts, its in the control panel under website, there is the ability to select different versions of PHP, and also ASP etc etc.